# Find the equation of a plane that is invariant with respect to the following transformation:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

> Find the equation of a plane that is invariant with respect to the following transformation:
>   \begin{pmatrix}4&-23&17\\ \:11&-43&30\\ \:15&-54&37\end{pmatrix}

Actually, I don't know the algorithm but tried to find it as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix}4&-23&17\\ \:11&-43&30\\ \:15&-54&37\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\z\end{pmatrix}$$

And by simplifying this we get

$$\begin{pmatrix}15&-54&36\\ 0&-\frac{61}{5}&\frac{49}{5}\\ 0&0&\frac{4}{61}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\z\end{pmatrix}=0$$
Which just implies that the equation has only trivial solutions. Could anyone please tell the right track?

$\textbf{Answer:}$ $3x-3y+z=0$

Comment: The question is to find a plane (i.e. a two dimensional subspace) that is invariant under your given transformation. This just means that a point in your plane gets sent to another point in your plane and you assumed that the points are fixed under the transformation.

Comment: @M.Wang Yeah, you're right. I got your point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this invariant plane passes through the origin, its equation is of the form $\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf x=0$, where $\mathbf n$ is some vector normal to the plane. If $\mathbf x'=M\mathbf x$, where $M$ is the matrix in your problem, then for $$\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x' = \mathbf n\cdot M\mathbf x = M^T\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x = 0$$ to represent the same plane, we must have $M^T\mathbf n = \lambda\mathbf n$ for some nonzero real $\lambda$, i.e., $\mathbf n$ is an eigenvector of $M^T$ with a real eigenvalue.

It turns out that even if we consider planes that don’t pass through the origin, we get the same solution, so we didn’t lose anything by restricting our attention to planes through the origin.

Comment: $\mathbf n\cdot M\mathbf x = M^T\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x$ how do you swap $M$ like this?

Comment: @VIVID This is one of the basic properties of inner products. For this particular inner product, write $\mathbf n\cdot M\mathbf x = \mathbf n^T(M\mathbf x)$ and reassociate, using the fact that the transpose of a product is the product of the transposes, reversed.